# Does the distribution of velocity matter in the fluid approximation?

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics

So for a perfect fluid in General relativity, my impression is the average velocity only matters and the distribution of velocities does not in the fluid approximation (otherwise I would have some dependence on temperature). Can someone point me to a reference or explain on why this is the case?

It's not obvious to me why an average description can work in general relativity since it's not a linear theory.

Comment: See (from page 505): https://archive.org/details/landau-and-lifshitz-physics-textbooks-series/Vol%206%20-%20Landau%2C%20Lifshitz%20-%20Fluid%20mechanics%20%282nd%20ed%2C%201987%29/page/505/mode/1up  ,

Comment: and page 1:  .... Accordingly, when we speak of infinitely small elements of volume, we shall always mean those which are “physically” infinitely small, i.e. very small compared with the volume of the body under consideration, but large compared with the distances between the molecules. The expressions fluid particle and point in a fluid are to be understood in a similar sense. If, for example, we speak of the displacement of some fluid particle,....

Comment: "...If, for example, we speak of the displacement of some fluid particle, we mean not the displacement of an individual molecule, but that of a volume element containing many molecules, though still regarded as a point." L&L

Comment: @TheTiler how does one decide/prove what a good volume is?

Comment: If we look at volume VI of L&L, after the establishment of Euler's equations (2.3) and the equations (134.7) and (134.8) they said that the equations do not take into account the friction internal and thermoconduction. (I have the French version where they mention this point for the relativistic case, 1971 edition), so the hypothesis of a perfect fluid appears after the equations are established.

Comment: and in particular in the relativistic case, the equations (134.7) and (134.8) express the adiabacity of the movement and according to "The absence of heat exchange between different parts of the fluid (and also, of course, between the fluid and bodies adjoining it) means that the motion is adiabatic throughout the fluid. Thus the motion of an ideal fluid must necessarily be supposed adiabatic." page 3

Comment: @TheTiler thank you would have loved to give you the bounty but alas you only left comments :/

Comment: No problem, the important thing is to know how to transmit the idea and I gained to have deepened my own knowledge, thank you to you too with your well-posed questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

A perfect fluid is in local thermal equilibrium, and the velocity distribution must be the one given by the equilibrium partition function. For a non-interacting gas this is the Maxwell-Juttner distribution. In thermal equilibrium the fluid is completely characterized by thermodynamic variables, for example energy density and pressure, and symmetries fix the form of the stress tensor,
$T_{\mu\nu}=(e,p,p,p)$ in the local rest frame. The stress tensor is the only input required by GR.